# Ebay Compatibility grabbing with php

Tags: php, parsing, screen-scraping, bearer-token, ebay-api

I have had this script to parse Compatibility from ebay, for example

1 - getting content of page - https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/173536511561
2 - parse "Bearer"
REGEX: '@{"value":"Bearer v^1.1(.*)",.*}@i'
3 - And then just get json of Compatibiles:

`$header = [ 'Authorization: Bearer v^1.1' . $matches[1], 'Content-Type: application/json', 'X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: EBAY-UK' ]; $url = 'https://api.ebay.com/parts_compatibility/v1/compatible_products/listing/173536511561?fieldgroups=full&limit=5000';`

And it works so far

But couple weeks ago "Bearer" disappear from page and i can't understand what happen May be some one knows how to fix it?

Thank you

now i cant understand how to simple get Bearer token
and i just have ebay server request

> {"error_code":"missing_token","error_description":"Bearer token is missing in authorization header. Should be under name 'Authorization'","errorMessage":{"error":[{"errorId":1002,"domain":"OAuth","category":"REQUEST","message":"Bearer token is missing in authorization header. Should be under name 'Authorization'","longMessage":"Bearer token is missing in authorization header. Should be under name 'Authorization'","actionToTake":"CORRECTINPUTDATA"}]},"extension":[]}

Comment: Are you saying that Ebay was outputting Bearer tokens into its pages, which you were then able to scrape? If that's the case then I'm not surprised it got removed, since that would be a serious security flaw.

Comment: But it's a bit difficult to tell exactly what you mean or what is happening, since you didn't really provide a [mre] of the scenario.

Comment: If you want to use the ebay API, why not just get an account, and then you can generate your own tokens? It _sounds like_ you're scraping tokens from a page and then using them with the API. Which doesn't really make sense...but like I said, you haven't provided a very clear description.